# BeautifulSoup create a <img /> tag

Tags: python, html, parsing, tags, beautifulsoup

I need to create a `<img />` tag.
BeautifulSoup creates an image tag like this with code I did:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html5")
tag = Tag(soup, name='img')
tag.attrs = {'src': '/some/url/here'}
text = soup.renderContents()
print text
```

Output: `<img src="/some/url/here"></img>`

How to make it? : `<img src="/some/url/here" />`

It can be of course done with REGEX or similar chemistry. However I was wondering maybe there is any standard way to produce tags like this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use `Tag()` to create new elements. Use the [`soup.new_tag()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautifulsoup-new-string-and-new-tag):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html5")
new_tag = soup.new_tag('img', src='/some/url/here')
some_element.append(new_tag)
```

The `soup.new_tag()` method will pass along the correct builder to the `Tag()` object, and it is the builder that is responsible for recognising `<img/>` as an empty tag.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<div></div>', "html5")
>>> new_tag = soup.new_tag('img', src='/some/url/here')
>>> new_tag
<img src="/some/url/here"/>
>>> soup.div.append(new_tag)
>>> print soup.prettify()
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <img src="/some/url/here"/>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **BS4** you can also do this:

```py
img = BeautifulSoup('<img src="/some/url/here" />', 'lxml').img

print(img)
print(type(img))
```

which will output:

```
<img src="/some/url/here"/>
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```